# Reminder Using Tkinter

Tags: python, time, tkinter

I am using Windows 7 *(32bit)*.

As a programming exercise, I have to make a reminder using `tkinter`.

To be more specified :

My main project is to help people who suffer from *alzheimer* disease.

So, one of my targets is to make a reminder for helping them do the necessary activities/things.

For example,

At *14:00 o'clock*, create a messagebox (and if it possible play a sound)..saying *"It's time to eat"*.
Then at *18:00 o'clock*, create a messagebox (and if it possible play a sound)..saying *"It's time for a walk"*.

etc...

How I can do this?
Is there a special module or some tools in python(or in tkinter) that can help me?

Before, coding in Visual Basic as remember I used something like "Timer"..But I can't remember more about this.. :P

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

At first thought you can have a tk config dialog, where you can add new rules, edit messagebox strings etc. Then you will have in which you will use the `time` module. From there you can access the system time.

If you want to display windows messageboxes, you can find them in the ctypes libary.

Answer (score 0):

for the time you can use:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

and for the messagebox you can use:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(None, 'it\'s time to eat!', 'reminder', 0x40)
#0x40 makes an ok button
```